# Using the calculate method of a MKDirections instance

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a really strange problem using the calculate method of a MKDirections object in a for loop. My code calculates the distances from the user’s current location to the locations of 3 different campsites but not all of the distances are calculated at the same point in the code. Here is my code below;

```
        for siteIndex in 0...countySites.count - 1 {

            var selectedSite = countySites[siteIndex]
            let destinationPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: selectedSite.locationCoordinate)

            request.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPlacemark)

            let distanceAndDirections = MKDirections(request: request)

            if currentCoordinate != nil {

                distanceAndDirections.calculate { (response, error) in
                    if error == nil {

                        let distanceInMetres = response?.routes.first?.distance
                        let distanceInMiles = distanceInMetres! / 1610
                        let roundedDistanceInMiles = Int(distanceInMiles.rounded())
                        distanceToSite = roundedDistanceInMiles

                        selectedSite.distance = distanceToSite
                        self.countySites[siteIndex] = selectedSite

                        print("distanceToSite = \(distanceToSite)")

                        if self.countySites.count > 1 {
                            if siteIndex == self.countySites.count - 1 {

                                print("BEFORE: countySites[0].distance = \(self.countySites[0].distance)")
                                print("BEFORE: countySites[1].distance = \(self.countySites[1].distance)")
                                print("BEFORE: countySites[2].distance = \(self.countySites[2].distance)")

                                self.countySites = self.sortByDistance(sites: self.countySites)

                                print("AFTER: countySites[0].distance = \(self.countySites[0].distance)")
                                print("AFTER: countySites[1].distance = \(self.countySites[1].distance)")
                                print("AFTER: countySites[2].distance = \(self.countySites[2].distance)")

                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                            }
                        }

                    } else {

                        print("Distance error: \(error.debugDescription)")

                    }
                }

            } else {
                print("currentCoordinate is nil")
            }
        }
```

I get the following output when I run the code on my device;

```
Got here!
distanceToSite = 224
distanceToSite = 235
BEFORE: countySites[0].distance = 224
BEFORE: countySites[1].distance = -1
BEFORE: countySites[2].distance = 235
AFTER: countySites[0].distance = -1
AFTER: countySites[1].distance = 224
AFTER: countySites[2].distance = 235
distanceToSite = 235
```

Can anyone work out how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented suggestions and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

since `calculate(completionHandler:)` is returning the values in asynchronous manner it is not guaranteed that all distances are calculated once you reach the last element in the list.
To achieve what you need you have to do the following:

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

for siteIndex in 0 ..< countySites.count {
    var selectedSite = countySites[siteIndex]

    if let currentCoordinate = currentCoordinate {
        let request = MKDirections.Request()
        request.source = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: currentCoordinate))
        request.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: selectedSite.locationCoordinate))
        let distanceAndDirections = MKDirections(request: request)

        dispatchGroup.enter()
        distanceAndDirections.calculate { (response, error) in
            if error == nil {

                let distanceInMetres = response?.routes.first?.distance
                let distanceInMiles = distanceInMetres! / 1610
                let roundedDistanceInMiles = Int(distanceInMiles.rounded())
                let distanceToSite = roundedDistanceInMiles

                selectedSite.distance = distanceToSite
                countySites[siteIndex] = selectedSite

                print("distanceToSite = \(distanceToSite)")

            } else {

                print("Distance error: \(error.debugDescription)")

            }
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }

    } else {
        print("currentCoordinate is nil")
    }
}

dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("BEFORE: countySites[0].distance = \(self.countySites[0].distance)")
    print("BEFORE: countySites[1].distance = \(self.countySites[1].distance)")
    print("BEFORE: countySites[2].distance = \(self.countySites[2].distance)")

    self.countySites = self.sortByDistance(sites: self.countySites)

    print("AFTER: countySites[0].distance = \(self.countySites[0].distance)")
    print("AFTER: countySites[1].distance = \(self.countySites[1].distance)")
    print("AFTER: countySites[2].distance = \(self.countySites[2].distance)")

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

You have to create a `DispatchGroup` and call `dispatchGroup.enter()` before calling `calculate(completionHandler:)`. Within the completionHandler of the same method you have to call `dispatchGroup.leave()`. Once the `enter` and `leave` call count has the same values, the closure for `dispatchGroup.notify` is executed.
Please note that I replaced your *Closed Range* `0...countySites.count - 1` with the *Half-Open Range* `0 ..< countySites.count`.

Kind Regards

Comment: Hi, I am getting the error message -> Use of unresolved identifier 'dispatchGroup'; did you mean 'DispatchGroup'? I changed dispatchGroup to DispatchGroup and I getting the error message ->                                                              Instance member 'enter' cannot be used on type 'DispatchGroup'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Comment: Thanks again, I've got it working! I created an instance of GroupDispatch and the rest was according to your modifications!

Comment: Can you tell me more about why this works and perhaps refer me to an online resource where I can learn more ?

Comment: @sjlearmonth sorry I had an error in the code snippet, which omitted the first line. I fixed it. For getting started with threading I think [this](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/understanding-threads-in-ios-5b8d7ab16f09) will be helpful. For getting a introduction to the `DispatchGroup` have a look at [this link](http://jordansmith.io/dispatch-groups-in-swift-3/)

Comment: @sjlearmonth feel free to accept the answer, if it helps :)

Comment: Hi, I am having a problem calling the ```calculate()``` method in the above code that you posted. I think I am making too many requests for distance calculation to Apple's servers as I am getting an error message which says ```Route information is not available at this moment``` and ```Directions Not Available```. How can I include a check on the ```isCalculating``` property of the ```MKDirections``` class before I call the ```calculate()``` method and avoid making too many requests. I don't understand enough about dispatch groups to work out what is going on here. Thanks.

Comment: @sjlearmonth I also guess you are doing to more requests and your are throttled (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html). Maybe check if you can reduce the amount of requests? Otherwise you need to store references to each `distanceAndDirections` property and check for `isCalculating`.